# Plus sign in URL field of bibtex export

Tags: bibtex, urls

I recently noted that citations exported from Oxford Academic have a plus sign in front of the URL.
For example, in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article-lookup/doi/10.1093/bioinformatics/btq180), the bibtex export contains the following field definition:

```
URL = { + http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btq180},
```

I took this to be a bug in the automatic citation export code and just deleted it when importing the citation.
But since I've now repeatedly seen this pattern, I started to wonder:
Is this some feature? Does the plus sign do something?

Comment: No it just looks absolutely wrong to me. The `url` field should contain only the non-escaped verbatim URL and nothing more. In this case, however, I would only export the `doi` field, the `url` adds nothing to it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe I'll drop a note to the publisher about this. (The `doi` field is given as well; the URL is maybe provided for people or tools that don't know how to construct it from the DOI.)